# How to filter data based off selections from two separate comboxes in a user form

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with two comboboxes (Year and Unit). I have a large data set that i want filtered based off the selection from both comboboxes, i.e. I select Year = 2013, Unit = 20A, I want it to filter out all the data with those two identifying references.

I have tried dependent comboboxes to no avail.

The only code i have to this point is to populate the comboboxes.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 Dim N As Long, i As Long
    With Sheets("LookUpLists")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        O = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row

    End With

    With cboYear
        .Clear
        For i = 1 To N
            .AddItem Sheets("LookUpLists").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        Next i
    End With

    With cboUnit
        .Clear
        For i = 1 To O
            .AddItem Sheets("LookUpLists").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on my understanding of your question it shouldn't be too hard. You can get the value of the comboboxes by using `CboYear.Value` and `cboUnit.Value`. Then you can use a `with` block with your sheets range and use two `.autofilter` referencing the respective `field:=` being your column to be filtered and the `Criteria1:=RespectiveComboBox.Value` containing the combobox selection. Note that not making a selection for either box will most likely result in an error. Also consider to put the filter condition on the `ComboBox_Change()` event to make sure it updates everytime you change the selection.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboYear_Change()

With Sheets("LookUpLists").Range("A1:AZ100") 'replace with an appropriate range
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=cboYear.Value 'edit to appropriate field
    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=cboUnit.Value 'edit to appropriate field
End With

End Sub

Private Sub cboUnit_Change()

With Sheets("LookUpLists").Range("A1:AZ100") 'replace with an appropriate range
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=cboYear.Value 'edit to appropriate field
    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=cboUnit.Value 'edit to appropriate field
End With

    End Sub
```

A separate note: you should always use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules. You can enable that automatically in VBA --> tools. It will help you find errors and mistakes (like not declaring O with a `Dim` statement)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Friendly hint: corrected spelling of `Criteria1` parameters in both Subs :-)